# Render layer of UIView which is not in the View Hierarchy

Tags: uiview, core-graphics, calayer

What i want to achieve is to take an image of an `UIView` which has not been added as a subview, present and do stuff with the image and afterwards add the view to the view hierarchy.

I've searched and tried now for a while and believe, that it is simply not possible.

---

Obviously the problem is, that the view hasn't been drawn (called `drawRect:` i guess) if it hasn't been added as a subview.
Actually i thought `renderInContext:` would call `drawRect/layer` on its own.

It isn't even enough to add it as subview right before draw it to an imageContext because it won't be rendered immediately.

I take the screenshot with `renderInContext:` with the layer of the view, see my code here:

```
[self.view addSubView:view];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -frame.origin.x, -frame.origin.y);

[view.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

So my question is, has anybody managed to render a **not visible** `UIView` and if how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is awkward.
After a mail conversation with a very kind apple dev support, we reviewed my code and we noticed that i simply set the `hidden` property to `YES`.  - Just don't do that.

So it is straight forward to make a screenshot of a view which is not in the view hierarchy.
It was total my fault why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to addd UIView to hierarchy but keep it hidden.

```
- (void)takeScreenSnapshot {

     UIView *capturedView = self.view;    
     UIView *hiddenView = self.hiddeniew;  //  hidden view which is 
                                           //  a part of capturedView   
     hiddenView.hidden = NO;

     BOOL retina = [self isRetinaDisplay];
     UIImage *image = [capturedView captureImageWithScale:(retina) ? 2.f : 1.f];

     hiddenView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Sadly not what i want. Even if it would work, i can't add the views before.